# How do I use requestAnimationFrame with Motorcycle and mostjs

Tags: javascript, typescript, mostjs, motorcycle

I am using Motorcycle to create a small application. I need to call a function on every requestAnimationFrame. Since it is a side effect, I know it must be done in an "effectful" component. However, mostjs doesn’t provide a source, such as it provides `periodic()` and `now()`, to make a requestAnimationFrame stream. How do I implement such a feature in my application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to do this in your application using a library such as [most-request-animation-frame](http://github.com/TylorS/most-request-animation-frame) which is @most/core ready and therefore 100% ready for usage with Motorcycle. It provides a function `requestAnimationFrames(): Stream<Time>` which will return a stream that emits the current time recursively scheduled with `requestAnimationFrame`.

Just as an FYI, the "current time" is determined using the `Scheduler` that the stream is run with and *not* the time that one might receive in the callback to `requestAnimationFrame((timestamp) => { ... })`. This way, time is injected as a dependency and is monotonic.